# I want to change how my pointer looks in R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I have created an R shiny app with a gauge(tachometer), with the pointer looking like:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT7A9.png)

But I want the pointer to look like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0eV2.png)

Here is my code

## Update the tachometer plot with the new data

```
  output$tachometer_plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    # Calculating the pointer coordinates
    pointer_angle <- 180 - ((tachometer_data[1] - 1) * 180 / 99)
    pointer_length <- 0.38 # Adjusting the pointer length
    pointer_x <- 0.5 + pointer_length * cos(pointer_angle * pi / 180)
    pointer_y <- 0.25 + pointer_length * sin(pointer_angle * pi / 180)
    
    custom_steps <- list(
      list(range = c(0, tachometer_data[2]), color = "#006F4E"),
      list(range = c(tachometer_data[2], tachometer_data[3]), color = "yellow"),
      list(range = c(tachometer_data[3], 100), color = "#991B56")
    )
    gauge_data <- data.frame(value = tachometer_data[1])
    plot_ly(gauge_data, type = "indicator", mode = "gauge", value = tachometer_data[1],
            gauge = list(axis = list(range = c(0, 100)), bar = list(thickness = 0.6, color = "transparent"),
                         bgcolor = "white", borderwidth = 2, bordercolor = "gray", steps = custom_steps,
                         dial = list(shape = "circle", bgcolor = "transparent"),
                         number = list(visible = FALSE))) %>%
      layout(margin = list(l = 20, r = 20), title = list(text = "Exposure to Carbon Intensive Industries", font = list(size = 14)),
             shapes = list(
               list(type = "path",
                    path = sprintf("M 0.5 0.5 L %f %f Z", pointer_x, pointer_y),
                    xref = "paper", yref = "paper",
                    fillcolor = "black", line = list(color = "black", width = 1))
             ),
             annotations = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.16, xref = "paper", yref = "paper",
                                     text = sprintf("%.1f", tachometer_data[1]),
                                     showarrow = FALSE, font = list(size = 30))))
```

Comment: could you please add sample data and full code of app to test?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and let me know how it looks (basically, in tachometer custom built `arrowPath` object will look like an arrow instead of a simple line)?

```
arrowPath <- paste0(
  "M 0.5 0.5 L ", pointer_x, " ", pointer_y,
  " L ", pointer_x - 0.03 * cos((pointer_angle + 10) * pi / 180), " ",
  pointer_y - 0.03 * sin((pointer_angle + 10) * pi / 180),
  " L ", pointer_x + 0.05 * cos(pointer_angle * pi / 180), " ",
  pointer_y + 0.05 * sin(pointer_angle * pi / 180),
  " L ", pointer_x - 0.03 * cos((pointer_angle - 10) * pi / 180), " ",
  pointer_y - 0.03 * sin((pointer_angle - 10) * pi / 180),
  " Z"
)
```

and use this `path` object in your code:

```
shapes = list(
  list(type = "path",
       path = arrowPath,
       xref = "paper", yref = "paper",
       fillcolor = "black", line = list(color = "black", width = 1))
),
```

If this works, customization can be done further.